# Getting 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime.'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am getting this error. Is there a way to debug the error?

The code is below and line 2064 is the line before the last line, 
"set rsTemp=ConnTemp.execute(InputQuery)"

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e57'

Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime.

AsPPage.asp, line 2064

```
<%
rsTemp.close
set rsTemp=nothing
ConnTemp.close
set ConnTemp=nothing
end sub

sub query2table(InputQuery, InputDSN, CompletedSection)

dim ConnTemp, rsTemp

set ConnTemp=server.createobject("adodb.connection")
ConnTemp.ConnectionTimeout = 0 ' Do not allow timeouts.
ConnTemp.open InputDSN

if CompletedSection = "Y" and instr(1, InputQuery, "Acknowledged_By") > 0 then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "Acknowledged_By", "CompletedBy")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "viewOrders.AcknowledgedBy AS CompletedBy", "viewOrders.CompletedBy")
end if

if CompletedSection = "Y" and instr(1, InputQuery, "AcknowledgeDate") > 0 then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "Date_Acknowledged", "CompletionDate")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewOrders.AcknowledgeDate AS Date_Acknowledged", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewOrders.AcknowledgeDate AS CompletionDate", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewOrders.CompletionDate, viewOrders.Ship_Status", ", viewOrders.CompletionDate, viewOrders.CompletedBy, viewOrders.Ship_Status")
end if

if instr(1, ucase(trim(InputQuery)), "DATE()") > 0 and Session("Database") = "SQLServer" then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "Date()", Session("CurrentDateSyntax"))
end if

if rsAppName("AllowFormOrders") = false then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "GROUP BY", "AND (viewOrders.FormOrder = 0) GROUP BY")
end if

if rsAppName("AllowPRIncentiveOrders") = false then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "GROUP BY", "AND (viewOrders.PRIncentive = 0) GROUP BY")
end if

if rsAppName("AllowSpecimenOrders") = false then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "GROUP BY", "AND (viewOrders.SpecimenOrder = 0) GROUP BY")
end if

if rsAppName("ShowRushColumnInApproversAndFulfillmentPages") = false then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewOrders.RushMaterialsASAP", "")
end if

if rsAppName("AllowRepositorySupplyBlinding") = false then
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting.BlindItemCount FROM", _
        ", -2 AS LineItemCount, 0 AS BlindItemCount FROM")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting.BlindItemCount, ", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "LEFT JOIN viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting ON viewOrders.OrderNumber = viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting.OrderNumber", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Waiting.BlindItemCount HAVING", " HAVING")

    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted.BlindItemCount FROM", _
        ", -2 AS LineItemCount, 0 AS BlindItemCount FROM")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted.BlindItemCount, ", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "LEFT JOIN viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted ON viewOrders.OrderNumber = viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted.OrderNumber", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_NonCompleted.BlindItemCount HAVING", " HAVING")

    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled.BlindItemCount FROM", _
        ", -2 AS LineItemCount, 0 AS BlindItemCount FROM")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled.BlindItemCount, ", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "LEFT JOIN viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled ON viewOrders.OrderNumber = viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled.OrderNumber", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Cancelled.BlindItemCount HAVING", " HAVING")

    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.BlindItemCount FROM", _
        ", -2 AS LineItemCount, 0 AS BlindItemCount FROM")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.BlindItemCount, ", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, "LEFT JOIN viewBlindItemCounts_Completed ON viewOrders.OrderNumber = viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.OrderNumber", "")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.LineItemCount, viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.BlindItemCount HAVING", " HAVING")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.BlindItemCount ORDER BY ", " ORDER BY ")
    InputQuery = replace(InputQuery, ", viewBlindItemCounts_Completed.LineItemCount ORDER BY ", " ORDER BY ")
end if

set rsTemp=ConnTemp.execute(InputQuery)
NumberOfFields=rsTemp.fields.count -1%>
```

Comment: Can you print the value of InputQuery before it is executed, and post it in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. The issue was resolved by manipulating data in smalldatetime data type from the database in Classic ASP code. One table in the DB had datetime as the data type on the database instead of smalldatetime. The change fixed the error and I was able to load the page completely.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to debug this type of issue is to put a break-point on the line that executes your SQL. Then using the immediate/watch/locals/autos window, you can grab the contents of the SQL statement before it is executed. Put this into a New Query window in MSSMS, or even in notepad. Often, you will see what your issue is just by looking at the final SQL. IE, no quotes around your date or something.

If you still don't see the problem, run it in MSSMS. It will sometimes give you more information about the issue.  If not, try to break the SQL down to smaller pieces until you figure out the exact problem.

If you still don't know what it is at this point, Google it, your likely not the first person to ever have this issue.

Hope this answers your question, "Is there a way to debug the error?"

Comment: Thank you Steve for your prompt response. I am using Classic ASP, I can add a breakpoint, but the debug button is grayed out on MS Visual Studio 2008. Any thought?

Comment: Been a while since I did the classic but you can, show the SQL in a Msgbox(). This helps with the first step, but a pain if you need to copy it to SQL Server. For that, you may have to get fancy and send it to another page (redirect) or show it in a input (textbox) or something. Usually you see the problem if you can see the SQL.

Comment: Actually you can debug ASP in Visual Studio. Its a crazy convoluted process but it actually works. Ill see if I can find the steps for you.

Comment: Issue resolved. The issue was with manipulating data in smalldatetime data type from the database in Classic ASP code. One table in the DB had datetime as the data type on the database instead of smalldatetime.